# CCValidator Updates

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have CCValidator installed in 3 different locations (servers where CC.NET runs).

The problem that I have is that 2 of them do not recognize CC.NET plugins that I have installed - specifically `conditional` elements within the `.config` file. One version of CCValidator works as expected with `conditional` elements, but the other 2 do not.

The `conditional` elements are coming into use more and more often. I need to find updates for CCValidator to recognize the plugins I have and use regularly.

I did not install the various instances of CCValidator and can find nothing about downloading the newest version or updates. I have checked several posts that included links that did not lead anywhere that helped.

Answer (score 1):

**CruiseControl.net configuration validation tool** is provided with ccnet installation. It has the same version as ccnet.

You should not install another version, as it is linked to **your** ccnet installation. If you have warnings or errors with the validator then :

- be sure to use the right CCValidator.exe under the `server` folder (not inside `ccvalidator`).
- upgrade your ccnet installation. v1.6.xxxx is stable enough and fix many thing from v1.5

For your information, I'm using ccnet v1.5.7385.122 and ccnet v1.6.7991.1 without any plugin error/issue.